# How to dynamically load node module for browserify transform

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I am working on a browserify transform that I hope will have the ability to have extensions.

```
//excerpt from package.json of my application that is using my transform and extension
"browserify": {
  "transform": [
    ["mytransform", {"extensions": ["my-extension"] } ]
  ]
}
```

In the example above, I want the user to be able to specify other node modules that are interpreted within my transform as an extension.

Within my transform code, I have the following to load the extensions:

```
//lines 347-349 of mytransform/index.js
var extensions = options.extensions.map(function(extensionId){
                                            return require(extensionId)();
                                          });
```

When I run my code, I see the following

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'my-extension'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at /Users/pdgreen/Documents/Personal/github/mytransform/index.js:348:52
    at Array.map (native)
    at module.exports (/Users/pdgreen/Documents/Personal/github/mytransform/index.js:347:39)
    at nr (/Users/pdgreen/Documents/Personal/github/myproject/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/module-deps/index.js:231:23)
    at /Users/pdgreen/Documents/Personal/github/myproject/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:48:21
    at /Users/pdgreen/Documents/Personal/github/myproject/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:127:35
```

My extension is available to node because if I do `require('my-extension')` within my application, it loads without issue.  It seems like the resolving code that runs for my transform is too restrictive.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my problem was related to symbolic links.  Since I was still developing my transform and extension, I had created symbolic links from my application to those modules.  I guess require was following the symbolic links and jumping out of my application node_modules directory so it couldn't resolve my extension.  Once I learned about [npm link](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-link.html) and started using it instead of standard symbolic links, everything started working.